# Having run time error with "delete[]"

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, delete-operator

I was trying to program my own List class on C++.

Here is the code:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
private:
    T *value, *valueHelper;
    int valueSize;

public:
    int size;

List()
{
    valueSize = 2;
    value = new T[valueSize];
    size = 0;
}


void Add(T val)
{
    size++;

    if (size > valueSize)
    {
        valueSize *= 2;
        valueHelper = new T[valueSize]; 

        memcpy(valueHelper, value, sizeof(T) * (size - 1));

        delete[](value);
        value = valueHelper;
    }

    value[size - 1] = val;

}


void Clear()
{
    delete[](value);
    size = 0;
    valueSize = 2;
    value = new T[valueSize];
}


T & operator[](int P)
{
    return value[P];
}

};
```

The problem appered when I used a class variable on this List Class.
When I do Clear to delete some memory, there are a run time error appers.

I have trying to check what cause this problem and I have find out that this line on the function Clear() is the error line:

```
delete[](value);
```

I can not understand, why?

Comment: Multiple deletes perhaps? And wich particular error BTW? (Aww, my daily (down-) vote limit is reached ;-( ...)

Comment: How are you using that code?

Comment: what is the type of T that reproduces the problem?

Comment: *Which* of your `delete[]` calls?

Comment: Some types (std::string generally being one) don't necessarily work well with just being memcpy'd and having the original object destructed. What types are you testing with?

Comment: By the way, you are calling your class `List` but it's more like a `vector`. Terminology can be important to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - ask mods for more - we need your down and close votes!  The future of SO depends on it! :)

Comment: @MartinJames Seriously! Did I do something wrong in judgeing/triaging questions! If so, please enlighten me ;) ...

Comment: @MartinJames I still have close votes at hand today ;-) ...

Comment: @MartinJames There's certainly no way to _'ask mods for more'_ ... So what do you want to tell me?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - just my way of saying that you are doing a very good job of close-voting the very, very many really bad questions on SO :)

Comment: @MartinJames THX! -blush- Here we go: [The mouse police never sleeps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f9XiQgMDuw) ;) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, but it could be likely it is because you will have copies made of the `List` instance, for example by returning it from a function or passing it as a non-reference argument to a function.

Copying of objects are implemented by the default copy-constructor generated by the compiler, but it only does *shallow* copying, meaning it will copy the pointers but not what they point to. So then you will have two copies with pointers pointing to the same memory, and when one object deletes that memory the others pointer will be invalid.

You also have a memory leak in that you don't have a destructor, so when an instance goes out of scope then  you loose the allocated memory forever.

You should also read about [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: You right. My T is a struct that contains pointer. Is there any way to pass this? and about the leak. that is way I have written the line delete[](value); on the Add function.